# AppleScript: Keystroke USB Device Button

Tags: applescript

Is there a simple way to use an AppleScript to keystroke a button on a USB device (like a joystick)?

Something like:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code usbInputA
```

Also, if it is possible, how do I determine the code for the buttons?

Comment: What is a *button on a USB device*?

Comment: Depends on the device, but essentially I want to be able to simulate the input from a device plugged in via USB.  If you were to plug a joystick or game controller into your USB port, pressing the buttons on the joystick should be recognizable as USB device input.  I'm wondering how I can make an AppleScript simulate those inputs.

Comment: This is not possible with AppleScript